# Form onreset Event after the form reset

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, reset

Here's a sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form onreset</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form onreset="myFunction();">
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="text" name="lname">
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("The form was reset!");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click the reset button, the form onreset event fires first, i.e. the alert message appears before resetting the form fields. How can it happen *after* the form fields rest?
I also tried the following to no avail:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form onreset</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="text" name="lname">
        <button type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="myFunction();">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("The form was reset!");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152904/call-a-function-after-form-reset

Answer (score 3):

Try it

```
function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("The form was reset!");}, 100); 

        }
```