# Weird form reset event behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I ran into weird problem when listening to form `reset` event.

Inside callback of `reset` event I check for input value, and it's not updated immediately, I have to wait until next tick, for example with `setTimeout(callback, 0)` or preventing default and triggering event manually with `el.reset()`

Here is [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/muzahuye/1/edit) so you can see what I'm talking about - after you insert some value into input and click reset button, no content should be added to `div` element.

I can see the same problem on Chrome as well as Firefox.

- Is it a bug in implementation or intended behavior?
- If the latter – why?
- Is there any better way to workaround it than doing setTimeout or preventing default and triggering event manually?

Comment: Why not just remove the `div` element? Then it doesn't behave the way you're describing. The form resets on the first tick. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/g8495/)**

Comment: It resets, but when checking for input value inside callback, it's still there.

Answer (score 2):

The reset event is called before anything is reset rather than after, to give you a chance to cancel the reset if you need to.

This SO question says the only way to do do something after the reset is to call a function on a timeout: [Call a function after form reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152904/call-a-function-after-form-reset)

Comment: It makes sense, but I like my method with preventing event and triggering it manually more than setTimeout. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that hack to this problem might be overriding `onreset` property.

There is **no guarantee** it works in other browers.

```
form.onreset=function(){
  var b = input.value;
  logger.innerHTML += b + "<br/>"; 
};
```

please find here example I've prepared http://jsbin.com/muzahuye/20/edit?html,js,output

works fine on firefox, at least 28

https://browserling.com/queue?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fmuzahuye%2F20%2F%3Foutput&browser=firefox&version=nightly